# Cannot access specific pages in laravel on XAMPP

Tags: php, windows, laravel, xampp

Laravel installation on XAMPP only shows pages in /public. When i try to go a page like /business/register which is in /resources. I get a 404 page. I've set the vhosts file on XAMPP properly. The code is below.

I've tried almost everything and even checked .htaccess. Couldn't find the problem.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/pos"
  ServerName pos.dev
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/pos">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews   
    AllowOverride all 
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
   </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

With this config, it should work

Answer (score 0):

check to make sure that there is .htaccess in you public folder

Comment: Yes, There is an .htaccess with `-option multiviews` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/pos/public"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/pos/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews   
    AllowOverride all 
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Direcroty>
```

i recommended using homestead https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead